# Handling backbutton on Windows Phone 10 app C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm searching from a while and I can't find how to handle the back button..
I saw a lot of examples and no one of them perform..

I'm trying to make an app with two pages and then, I wanna use the back button to goBack on the first page. I make an universal app with Visual Studio 2015 and I didn't find an SDK for Visual Studio 2015 Windows Phone, so maybe it would be better to have an SDK, maybe my error came from here?

Thank for your read and your futur answers

Answer (score 0):

In order to go back insert this code in your second's page constructor.

```
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent ("Windows.Phone.PhoneContract", 1, 0)) {  
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += (s, a) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BackPressed");
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
            a.Handled = true;
        }
    };
}
```

Also there isn't a VS 2015 Phone SDK, you'll download the [UWP Dev tools](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/install-dev-tools-visual-studio-2015) and be ready to start developing

Comment: WHat do you mean by <second's page constructor.>? Thank for your help and I'm making a UWP for my Windows Phone 10

Comment: Let's say that your 2nd page is name Page2, then in the .cs file there's a method Page2() {} that's the constructor of your page, insert the above code there, and don't forget to mark my response as an answer if I helped you

Answer (score 0):

I was watching the TV and I got the answer alone. It's an UWP (Universal Windows App) then it means, it works on computer or phone as well. The controls/input aren't the same. So I thought, maybe my app dosen't have the good library/includes, something like it. In references, I had an extension "Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP" and it works with the code below !

```
public Settings()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed +=
        HardwareButtons_BackPressed;       
    }

    void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender,
        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Frame != null && this.Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            this.Frame.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

Thank for your help !